# Found a Tag Bug

Tags: bug

There is a Black Bo tag which means nothing and doesn't have a wiki on it either. Shouldn't it be removed?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A questioner must have added that tag as a typo. Note that there isn't any restriction to stick to existing tags. The fix is just to edit the question to not use that tag (as I just did). A tag that is completely unused is automatically deleted after a while.